# Log onto internet using DD WRT

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, dd-wrt

I'm at a hotel right now and I want to connect my DD WRT router to the internet so I can strengthen the internet in my room. The connection here requires an HTTP logon, how can I do this from DD WRT?

Comment: what if you set the connection the way you want then then authenticate the laptop (connected to the router) to the hotel's internet. Their connection may see the IP address of the router and then authenticate it to get online.

Comment: without knowing the authentication that the hotel uses, it's really hard to say.

Comment: Usually the authentication is via catch-and-release, so you'll need to describe exactly what the sequence is when you authenticate with your laptop.  It is probable you can simulate it from a PC behind your router.